# How to change the text direction in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, right-to-left

I need "right to left" text direction to write in Persian.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Enable Complex Text Layout (CTL) support using (sources: [1](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Glossary#Complex_Text_Layout_.28CTL.29), [2](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Languages_Using_Complex_Text_Layout), [3](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Languages)):

  Tools → Options → Language Settings → Languages

It may be necessary to restart LibreOffice after enabling CTL.

Then:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> - switch to right-to-left text entry

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> - switch to left-to-right text entry.

If the shortcuts don't work using <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd>,
try <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a toolbar icon for this? So I won't need to remember the shortcut.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka: If you go to the menu Tools -> Customize, and then click on the tab "Toolbars", and then select the toolbar "Formatting", you'll see the buttons "Left-to-right" and "Right-to-left" there, although I can't get them to appear.

Comment: What about any text box? For instance, Yahoo Mail Text Box? How can I change text direction there?

Comment: Tools → Options → Language Settings → Languages , and enable Asian Languages helped me.

Comment: I changed the locale setting to persian then Complex Text Layout appeared on the left column. (ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 15):

**Add Direction Buttons like MS-WORD**

As you remember in MS WORD there were to buttons in standard menu which acted as shortcut.

Go to  *VIEW>TOOLBARS>CUSTOMIZE*

Select the tab "*TOOLBARS*"

Select "STANDARD"

Press the button "ADD"

Select Category " Format"

From the right pane select "**RIGHT TO LEFT**" & "**LEFT TO RIGHT**"

Comment: This question is about LibreOffice, not MS Word.

Comment: I followed the this exact same procedure in LibreOffice Impress and it worked!

Comment: And then what? Where do I see the new buttons?

Answer (score 8):

Does this solution work?

> - Ctrl+Shift+D or Ctrl+Right Shift Key - switch to right-to-left text entry
> - Ctrl+Shift+A or Ctrl+Left Shift Key - switch to left-to-right text entry

from https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Languages_Using_Complex_Text_Layout

Comment: Yes. but before that we should enable CTL support using: 
Tools -> Options -> Language Settings -> Languages.
from: [https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Glossary#Complex_Text_Layout_.28CTL.29](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Glossary#Complex_Text_Layout_.28CTL.29)

Comment: I have CTL and Asian disabled, how can I enable them please ?

Answer (score 6):

Tools >> Options >> Language Settings >> Languages >> Default Languages for Documents >> Complex text layout >> Select your language (Persian).
Now you could use:

- Ctrl+Shift+D or Ctrl+Right Shift Key - switch to right-to-left text
  entry
- Ctrl+Shift+A or Ctrl+Left Shift Key - switch to left-to-right
  text entry

Comment: Thank you, it's solved.

Comment: @M.Rostami I'm glad :)

Answer (score 4):

In Libreoffice 3, in the menu of tools > Options > language settings > languages

In Enhanced language support section, you should check "Enabled for Complex text layout (CTL)" to enable the key combination for text writing directions.
Without this option, your Ctrl+Shift keys won't take effect.
When enabled, then you can use

- Ctrl+Shift+D or Ctrl+Right Shift Key - switch to right-to-left text
  entry
- Ctrl+Shift+A or Ctrl+Left Shift Key - switch to left-to-right
  text entry