# How to change the text direction in LibreOffice (2021)?

Tags: libreoffice, right-to-left

I have text in Hebrew and while I can change the alignment, the punctuation marks would be on the wrong side of the sentence. I have tried the following methods:

1. Following the method here: https://superuser.com/a/726306 I enabled CTL, restarted LibreOffice, and tried pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`D` and `Ctrl`+`Right Shift`. Neither of them worked.
2. Following the method here: https://superuser.com/a/795738 I went to VIEW>TOOLBARS>CUSTOMIZE, selected "TOOLBARS", selected as the target "STANDARD", in the category selected "Format", pressed the right arrow on the "RIGHT TO LEFT" & "LEFT TO RIGHT" items, pressed Ok. I see no changes in the interface.

What I can do is right click on the text, select "paragraph", go to the alignment tab, change text direction to right to left, press Ok. While that works, I write a lot of bilingual papers and I would like an easier way than that. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you suggested, and then save it as template that you can always return to. File > Templates > save it as template.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189027)